# http-server blocks the script on travis CI

Tags: testing, gruntjs, continuous-integration, travis-ci

Here is my `.travis.yml`:

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - "node"
before_install:
  - npm install -g grunt-cli
  - npm install -g http-server
  - npm install -g bower
install:
  - npm install
  - bower install
services:
  - http-server
script: grunt mocha
after_success: "./travis.sh"
```

I need the `http-server` to be listening to 8080 port when my `grunt mocha` task is running. But when travis CI job starts the server it just hangs the whole pipeline. On my local machine I start `http-server` in one console tab and `grunt mocha` in another. What is the workaround here?

I have found a [post](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-get-Travis-CI-to-start-my-Django-server-and-then-run-my-tests-on-it) with the same question unanswered.

Here's what travis shows me in log:

```
...
$ http-server
Starting up http-server, serving ./
Available on:
  http:127.0.0.1:8080
  http:172.17.4.241:8080
Hit CTRL-C to stop the server
No output has been received in the last 10 minutes, this potentially indicates a stalled build or something wrong with the build itself.
The build has been terminated
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution turned out to be very simple. I  made `http-server` run in background by appending `&` to the command. So I created file `start-server.sh` with following contents:

```
#!/bin/bash
http-server &
sleep 3
```

And added `'./start-server.sh'` in `before_script` section of my `.travis.yml`

Answer (score 2):

https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-get-Travis-CI-to-start-my-Django-server-and-then-run-my-tests-on-it

I believe I wound up running manage. py runserver in the background, let me know if that works for you (not on my development machine atm and I'm having trouble finding the amended script on my github)

So in your case I'd try

```
- http-server &
- grunt mocha
```